# Detecting hand on Image View object?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm trying to create a mobile AR app to create a virtual exercise.
Now I'm able to bring the robot body to tracking the body.
I use framework ARKit developer in Xcode.

I have doubts about

How do I know if Robot's hand is touching the yellow dot?
yellow dot is image View.
[yellow score point picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycGZv.png)
[Image when running the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MccJ.jpg)

Thank you so much for your help in advance.